# Flyway fails on migrate with schema not found - Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jdbc, flyway

I have below flyway configuration set in my application-test.yml

```
spring:
  flyway:
    enabled: true
    create-schemas: true
    default-schema: testit
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    user: sa
    password: sa
    schemas: testit
    locations: filesystem:database/postgres/testit/testit
    tablespace: testit
-------------------
  r2dbc:
    pool:
      initialSize: 1
      maxSize: 2
      maxIdleTime: 120000
```

I can see that migrations scripts are picked up by flyway and are getting executed, but in some point it fails with below error:

```
-----------------
SQL State  : 3F000
Error Code : 0
Message    : ERROR: schema "testit" does not exist
  Position: 14
Location   :  ()
Line       : 1
Statement  : CREATE TABLE "testit"."flyway_schema_history" (
    "installed_rank" INT NOT NULL,
    "version" VARCHAR(50),
    "description" VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    "type" VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    "script" VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
    "checksum" INTEGER,
    "installed_by" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    "installed_on" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    "execution_time" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "success" BOOLEAN NOT NULL
) TABLESPACE "testit"
```

Note: I even have `create schema if not exists testit authorization sa` in first migration script inside of `database/postgres/testit/testit` path.

Not able to understand the reason behind why it is not able to find the required schema to create `flyway_history_schema` table.

**build.gradle** dependencies I have:

```
Spring boot version - 2.7.11
Java version - 17

testImplementation('org.flywaydb:flyway-core')
testImplementation('org.springframework:spring-jdbc:5.3.8')
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc'
implementation 'org.postgresql:r2dbc-postgresql'
implementation 'io.r2dbc:r2dbc-pool'
runtimeOnly ('org.postgresql:postgresql')
```

**TestContainer specific dependencies**:

```
testContainerVersion = "1.18.3"

testImplementation("org.testcontainers:testcontainers:$testContainerVersion")
testImplementation("org.testcontainers:junitjupiter:$testContainerVersion") 
testImplementation("org.testcontainers:postgresql:$testContainerVersion") 
testImplementation("org.testcontainers:r2dbc:$testContainerVersion")
```

I'm using jdbc connection url for `spring.flyway.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:49165/testit`

**Testcontainer class**:

```
@Testcontainers
public class ContainersConfig {

    @Container
    static PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgresContainer =
            new PostgreSQLContainer<>(DockerImageName.parse("postgres:14.6"))
                    .withDatabaseName("testit")
                    .withUsername("sa")
                    .withPassword("sa");

    @AfterAll
    void stopContainer() {
        postgresContainer.stop();
    }
    static {
        Startables.deepStart(postgresContainer).join();
    }

    @DynamicPropertySource
    private static void setDatasourceProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {

        registry.add("spring.r2dbc.url", () ->
                "r2dbc:postgresql://"+ postgresContainer.getHost() + ":" +
                        postgresContainer.getMappedPort(PostgreSQLContainer.POSTGRESQL_PORT)
                + "/" + postgresContainer.getDatabaseName());
        registry.add("spring.r2dbc.username", postgresContainer::getUsername);
        registry.add("spring.r2dbc.password", postgresContainer::getPassword);
        registry.add("spring.flyway.url", postgresContainer::getJdbcUrl);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced your settings and Flyway migration works as expected. The only difference is that I let Flyway create the database schema. I don't have any `create schema` statements in the migration scripts itself.

My setting:

```
spring.flyway.create-schemas=true
spring.flyway.default-schema=testit
spring.flyway.schemas=testit
spring.flyway.tablespace=testit
```

Flyway history:
[image]

PS: it was H2 in-memory database

Comment: Without the `create schema` it still does not work for me, one thing to note is I'm using TestContainer for postgres

Comment: In this case please update the original question. There is nothing related to test containers. Neither in dependencies nor in url.

Comment: I have updated original question now with Testcontainer details

Comment: I have managed to resolve my issue, for some reason flyway_schema_history table was not able to create under `testit` tablespace as a result when flyway retries transaction is rolled back along with the schema.
Resolved this by removing tablespace property from configuration and tables are getting created under default tablespace without any issue!